# Oracle APEX - Default Primary Key Value 't1000'

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

When add new row in interactive grid the id column  value automatic create t1000 , how I can handle this issue?

Because when  use the below code  to set value in  the item  when selected change (dynamic action related to interactive grid ) , appear error ajax invalid number.

```
this.data.selectedRecords.length != 1
  ? ""
  : this.data.model.getValue(this.data.selectedRecords[0], "ID");
```

Because the region refreshing Depends on item value  ,

```
  (select 1 from dual where id=:p000_id )
```

the id column is number (Page Items to Submit "p000_id" )

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? You haven't shown the error. What does "set value in the item when selected change" mean? What does "Because the region refreshing Depends on item value" mean? Please clarify what's going on.

Comment: thanks for your comment , the selected change it's dynamic action related to interactive grid .